# How to print from 1 to 9 with three numbers in a line using loops

Tags: c, loops

I am coding a tic tac toe game in C. I am stuck at making a board like this:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

I want to use loops so that I dont have to use a printf function with many `\n`'s and `\t`'s...

Here's my attempt:

```
for (i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t");
    for (j=i;j<=i+2;j++)
    {
        printf("%c\t",boarddots[j]);
    }
    if (i==3)
    break;
}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: @chux thats what i tried

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you could adapt it to your actual needs:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
{
    printf("%d", i);  // print numbers one by one
    if (0 == i % 3)
        printf("\n"); // start new line if current number is divisible by 3
}
```

P.S. Sorry for possible typos

Comment: `printf(i);` should not compile. Try `printf(" %d", i);` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Basile Starynkevitch. So, latter is up to the topic-starter :)

Comment: @YurySchkatula thats great, can you tell me something for array? I mean I haave to put an 'X' or 'O' (depending on the user) so I have to use arrays

Comment: @user2978059, the same idea: use "/" and "%" operators to get column and row from item number (1-9) and vice versa. And don't forget: arrays are zero-based indexes, not 1-based (so shift it by one).

Comment: @YurySchkatula that was a great help! but there is a little problem, I am using char array to show these numbers because I will later have to change them into 'X' or 'O'

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
{
  for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
  {
    printf("%d ", (row * 3) + column + 1);
  }
  printf ("\n");
}

/*
output:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition `for (i=0;i<=9;i++)` iterated once too many. Personally, I would uses a 2D array such as `char board [3][3]`, but one step at a time to help with your immediate question.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char boarddots[] = "--O-XX-O-";

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t");
        printf("\t%c",boarddots[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do print as a string and use string truncation:

```
char boarddots[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
int loop;

for (loop=0; loop<9; loop+=3)
    printf ("%.3s\n", &boarddots[loop]);
```

You don't need a NULL on the end of the char array as the truncation takes care of that.